# How to generate password for users and send them email?

Tags: bash, file, authentication, email, passwords

I have a file with the list of users, I found a way how to generate for each user random password, but didn't know how to select each user their username and password and send them via email (email example `username@example.com`)
the script sends each user an email with each password from the file, that is, if there are 5 users, then each of them will receive 5 emails and 5 different passwords.

Generate Password

```bash
#!/bin/bash
file=$(cat /tmp/user_names.txt)

for line in $file
do
    passrand=$(openssl rand -base64 12) 
    echo -e "$line" "$passrand"
done
```

Send email

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for maillogin in $(cut -f1 -d ' ' /tmp/u_p.txt) || pass=$(cut -f2 -d' ' /tmp/u_p.txt)
do
  for pass in $(cut -f2 -d' ' /tmp/u_p.txt)
  do
    echo "Hello your login is" $maillogin "and password is" $pass | mail -s "Test Mail" "${maillogin}@example.com"
  done
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first script is ok.

For the second, you need to read line after line. So, do not use nested loops to read login and password. Use `read` command and decompose line:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

UP_FILE="/tmp/u_p.txt"
while read -r
do
    # maillogin <- line without any characters *after first* space (space included)
    maillogin="${REPLY%% *}"
    # pass <- line without any characters *before first* space (space included)
    pass="${REPLY#* }"
    echo "Hello your login is $maillogin and password is $pass" | mail -s "Test Mail" "${maillogin}@example.com"
done < "${UP_FILE}"
```